# User login not working

Tags: php, authentication, forum, phpbb

I am developing a forum using phpBB. It has a problem with authentication. Users have to login very frequently, almost on every HTTP request. What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your login form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='autologin' value=1>
```

I had the same problem on my website and adding this line solved it.

Comment: which login form??can you tell??

Comment: The login form where you type your username and your password.

Comment: can u tell me name and loaction of this file

Comment: You are the one who wrote the login form. I can't guess in which file you decided to put it.

Comment: I think its beacuse many users of my forum are under one LAN,so same ip for all and therefore ip conflict.am i correct??how to solve this issue??

Comment: http://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/style/artodia_helion/demo/  i used this template can you plz tell me where i have t add this <input type='hidden' name='autologin' value=1>
line